Showing a View after the 'Button' is pressed
I am designing a simple iOS application that performs a few simple calculation then presents the results on a second View.
The views are:

ContentView
ResultsView

In the previous days of Xcode, one could present the second view within a ButtonView.
Now that I am using Xcode 16.0 with iOS 18.0 things look like they have changed.
Can I present the ResultsView using a Button ??
The code for the ContentView follows"
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Bindable var rData = ResonantData()
    @Bindable var dData = DesiredData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color(.black)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack{
                    Title()
                    Spacer()
                    Notes()
                    
                    // Creates the top GroupBox
                    GroupBox(label: Label("Resonant", systemImage: "chart.bar.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)){
                            Text("Enter in the field below, the Current Resonant Frequency (Mhz), as seen on your Analyser.")
                            TextField("Resonance (Mhz)", text: $rData.frequency)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        }.padding()

                    // Creates the bottom GroupBox
                    GroupBox(label: Label("Desired", systemImage: "antenna.radiowaves.left.and.right.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)){
                            Text("Enter in the field below, the Desired Resonant Frequency (Mhz).")
                            TextField("Desired (Mhz)", text: $dData.frequency)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        }.padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("Results View") {
                        ResultsView()
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct Title: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Group {
                    Image(systemName: "s.circle.fill")
                    Image(systemName: "w.circle.fill")
                    Image(systemName: "r.circle.fill")
                }
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
            Text("Adjust")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.top, 1)
        }
    }
}
struct Notes: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Note:")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                .padding(.trailing, 320)
            
            Text("SWR Adjust is a simple Application that allows you to adjust the SWR ratio of your Dipole and Verticle antenna.")
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .font(.system(size: 18))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding(.leading)
        }
    }
}

And the code for the ResultsView is:
import SwiftUI

struct ResultsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ResultsView()
}


You never were able to do this. Did you mean to use a NavigationLink instead of a Button?

Hey Sweeper.   I am sure it was a Button, but NavigationLink was also used after I discovered its existance.
I thought seeing that it is only a two view application, I could do this via a Button.
What's ya thoughts??

The error I see is:
Result of 'ResultsView' initializer is unused

You could do this with a button by introducing a Bool state like showResults that gets toggled by the button to display the results: if showResults { ResultsView() } else { //... your initial input views }. Your initial input views could be turned into an InputView struct, for convenience. If you made your code reproducible, it would be easier to provide you an actual answer with working code.

Thanks Andrei, much appreciated, yep, makes sense.   Thanks again.
